# Vector Space - Removal from both sides

Tags: vector-spaces, proof-writing

> Given $V$ a vector space, and $A$, $B$, $C$ as it's members, How can I prove this:
>
> $$A + B = A + C  \implies  B = C$$

I'm sorry for my Mathematical English. I don't know the exact Mathematical words, so please, bear with me. Please feel free to edit the way I wrote the question. This is my first and I haven't gotten a clue on how to write properly in this environment.

Comment: See [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a guide on how to typeset mathematical formulas on this site.

Comment: The DEFINITION of vector space requires that every vector have an additive inverse!  Just add -A to both sides of the equation.

Comment: My Professor has forbidden me to add -A to both sides as that is what I'm actually trying to prove... First I have to prove that I can Add -A to both sides and then use this proof for other theorems...
How can I prove this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone was interested :

> $$B = B + 0 = B + ( A + (-A) ) = (B + A) + (-A) = (A + B) + (-A)$$

We know (A + B) equals (A + C) so we'll have :

> $$(A + B) + (-A) = (A + C) + (-A) = C $$

which implies

> $$B = C $$